# select doesnt make ajax call after div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some functions inside the same div. Everything is working good, but only in first time. After that, nothing works.

I have a select2 with change ajax call:

```
$('#category').change(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var s = document.getElementById("category");
var strUser = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('caller', 'PrintData');
formData.append('id', strUser);
$.ajax({ url: '../inc/call.php',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(output) {
        $('#data').html(output);
    }
});
})
```

The select2 contains the categories and it will list all the rows that belong to that category. So far, so good.

After the call, it will list all the results as a table with 3 buttons. One of them uses ajax call to delete that field.
To listen that button click, I use the following:

```
$('#reloader').on( "click", "button", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let button = $(this); 
let id = button.data("id"); 
let func = button.data("function");
let code = button.data("action");

if(func == "delete"){
    DeleteData(id, code);
}else if(func == "edit"){
    window.location = button.data("link")
}
});
```

When I click the button to delete the row, the above function calls the following function:

```
function DeleteData(id, code)
 {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "Do you want to delete " + code + "?" ,
        type: 'question',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm: function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            $.ajax({ url: '../inc/call.php',
            data: {
                dados: JSON.stringify(id),
                caller: 'DeleteData',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            type: 'POST'})
             .done(function(response){
                swal('Done!', response.message, response.status);
                updateDiv("reloader");
                $('#category').select2();

             })
             .fail(function(response){
                swal('Oops...', response.message, response.status);
                updateDiv("reloader");
                $('#category').select2();
             });
          });
        },
        allowOutsideClick: false     
     });
};
```

My problem occurs after this ajax call.
As it may seem, after I call a function that "refresh" the entire div with `updateDiv("reloader");` . Then, I try to transform the select into select2 with `$('#category').select2();` but it doesnt work.

Basically the select transforms into a normal select and the code to turn it into a select2 doesnt work. Beside that, even if I change the value in select 2, it doesnt make the ajax call to list the results (`$('#category').change(function(e){`)

This way I would like your help to one of two solutions:
1- Make this simple thing work, so after refresh the select becomes select2 and it works with change function I created;
2- After refresh, make it work as above but with default selection the last one that would list everything to keep working (to avoid selecting again and again the category and wait the list of data) (best option);

Any help would be appreciated.
Hope the thread is well presented. If need to change something please tell, I'll update it. Thanks.

Comment: Please use $('body').delegate('#category','change',function(){})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use

$('body').delegate('#category','change',function(){

})

because some time developer using datatable
datatable not reading next page direct dom

Comment: It seems to work now but the select doesn't come back as select2. The code $('#category').select2(); doesnt transform it. Any suggestion?